# broadcaster permission for com.google.android.gms.analytics.ANALYTICS_DISPATCH

Tags: android, google-analytics, android-permissions, android-broadcastreceiver

I recently did a code scan on my Android source code using HPFortify service. They reported security vulnerability regarding google analytics receiver. They suggested to use the broadcaster permission to reduce the attack vector. This way you are restricting broadcaster, otherwise any malicious application can send the intent and broadcast receiver will process it.

Here is my AndroidManifest file.

```
  <receiver
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver"
      android:enabled="true">
          <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.ANALYTICS_DISPATCH"/>
          </intent-filter>
   </receiver>
   <service
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService"
      android:enabled="true"
      android:exported="false"/>
```

I am trying to figure out the broadcaster permission for AnalyticsReceiver. According to HpFortify the broadcast receiver should look like similar to this:

```
<receiver
   android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver"
   android:permission="SOME-GOOGLE-ANALYTICS-PERMISSION"
   android:enabled="true">
       <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.ANALYTICS_DISPATCH"/>
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

---

**Edit 1:**
I am also looking for the source code to figure out the right permission. But I couldn't find the google analytics source code.